# How to compare an item in a IEnumerable<t> to the next item in the list?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to go through a IEnumerable in order to check for duplicates and remove them in order as in:
a method that takes a IEnumerable and returns a IEnumerable and filters out doubles like in the example:
AAABBAACCC becomes ABAC
In order to accomplish this I need a way to query the IEnumerable and compare each item to the next one and if they are different then add them to a new IEnumerable and return that, or compare each item to the next one and if they are the same then remove the first item.
I came up with something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) 
  {
    var query = from c in iterable
                where c != c.Next
                select c;
    return query;
  }
```

The problem is that c.Next does not exist. Is there a way to do this ? or is it not possible with Linq?

Comment: Why use linq if a loop would be much more readable?

Comment: You can use `Distinct` Linq extension and provide comparer

Comment: @LeVu `Distinct` will remove non-adjacent duplicate.

Comment: @Fildor I tried with different loops but there seems to be a problem when messing with IEnumerable<T> as in it is passed in a string and it returns a char.

Comment: @LeVu how can you tell the comparer you are talking about the next item in the IEnumerable<T>? I tried Distinct but it removes also the non consecutive duplicates.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UZHAeg => compare to your attempts.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can use in LINQ to "get the next thing" is `Zip`. Specifically, you `Zip` with the same enumerable, but with the first element skipped.

Your query would translate to:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
    => iterable.Zip(iterable.Skip(1)).Where(x => !x.First.Equals(x.Second)).Select(x => x.First);
```

However, your logic here is flawed. The output for "AAABBAACCC" is "ABA", because the last "group" has no "next" thing that is different. If you limit `T` to all reference types, you could add a `null` at the end of `iterable.Skip(1)`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
    where T: class
    => iterable.Zip(iterable.Skip(1).Append(null))
        .Where(x => !x.First.Equals(x.Second)).Select(x => x.First);
```

This works because nothing `Equals` null, hence guaranteeing always keeping the last "group".

I would do this as a loop, checking the previous item.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) {
    if (!iterable.Any()) {
        yield break;
    }
    T lastSeen = iterable.First();
    yield return lastSeen;
    foreach (var t in iterable) {
        if (!lastSeen.Equals(t)) {
            yield return t;
        }
        lastSeen = t;
    }
}
```

Side note: you can't use `!=` with an unconstrained generic parameter `T`, so I changed it to `!Equals`, but bear in mind that this won't work with nulls.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new List<string>(){"A","A","A","B","B","A","A","C","C","C"};
        foreach(var item in UniqueInOrder(items))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        // Oder
        foreach(var item in UniqueInOrderLinq(items))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>( IEnumerable<T> input ) where T: IEquatable<T>
    {
        if( input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        T prev = input.First();
        yield return prev;
        foreach( T item in input.Skip(1) )
        {
            if(!item.Equals(prev))
            {
                yield return item;
                prev = item;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrderLinq<T>( IEnumerable<T> input ) where T: IEquatable<T>
    {
        if( input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        return input.Aggregate( new List<T>(), (acc, next) => {if(!acc.LastOrDefault()?.Equals(next) ?? true) {acc.Add(next);} return acc; });
    }
}
```

Answer from @Fildor . Thanks mate, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

To improve on your existing answer, we can do this without querying the source multiple times:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if(input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    var isFirst = true;
    T prev = default;
    foreach( T item in input)
    {
        if(isFirst)
        {
            yield return item;
            prev = item;
            isFirst = false;
        }
        else if(!comparer.Equals(item, prev))
        {
            yield return item;
            prev = item;
        }
    }
}
```